# Sql server database restoring from backup, sql users without login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, database-user

After restoring a database from another SQL server, set database comes with database users without login. Do these users have any actual functionality or they are practically dead users? I've looked around for information about this and I couldn't find conclusive answer to this question.
The closest I got to an answer was this:

> "When you attach a database created on another server, you transfer
> the logins associated with it on the original server, but the SQL
> logins are not transferred, as they are defined on the Server, not the
> database. The database backup, or MDF and LDF files don't contain the
> info about SQL logins, only about database users. Therefore, the error
> message."

Are these database users point of vulnerability. Is there a way for them to be used?

Comment: In theory a user that had impersonation rights could impersonate them and do whatever those users could do, but such a user probably has other methods anyway.

Comment: If you're concerned about the security of these orphaned Users, and don't plan to restore their Logins, why not just delete them from the database on this server you restored the database to?

Comment: That was my question, I'm no aware how exactly they function if at all.

Comment: @Peter Heads up, idk if you intended to reply to me but you need to use @ and the username (like I just did to you) to alert someone in the comments. If so, your question differs than mine. I'm just asking, why don't you just delete the orphaned Users?

Comment: @J.D. I was curious if those db users serve any purpose to begin with and if they were a security risk, because I'm not aware of their function. I assumed maybe they were serving some local function for the DB it self like linked to a procedure or something like that and me deleting them would result of me breaking part of the DB. That's why I was looking for more information.